# java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission /usr/share/java/jsp-api-2.0.jar read)

Tags: java, security, tomcat, debian, lenny

I am trying to deploy me application to Tomcat 5.5 on Debian Lenny. I am getting the following exception:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission /usr/share/java/jsp-api-2.0.jar read)
```

I'm not sure what to do.

**Solution**

Add the following line to /etc/tomcat5.5/policy.d/04webapps.policy:

```
grant codeBase "file:/var/lib/tomcat5.5/webapps/mywebapp/-" { permission java.security.AllPermission; };
```

Comment: Tomcat 5.5 is quite old. Do you really need this old version? Maybe your problem is gone, if you use a newer version.

Comment: It ships with Debian Lenny and I didn't want to install my own version. I'm doing this on a local server just for testing purposes, I hope a more recent version of Tomcat will be available in the production environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I smells like an SecurityManager.

It is a message from the Java Security-Manager not from the filesystem. A class within this jar-archive tries to access a file, which is not allowed by the policy.

Take a look at this really similar problem: http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/tomcat-javasecurityaccesscontrolexception-access-denied-loggingproperties-read/

The Solution ist to allow reading of files in the `catalina.policy`

Answer (score 3):

try executing as root `chmod +r /usr/share/java/jsp-api-2.0.jar`

Comment: Its a message from the Java Security-Manager not the filesystem. A class within this path tries to access an file, which is not allowed by the policy.