# Tomcat AccessControlException:access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "logs" "read")

Tags: tomcat, securitymanager

I'm using `Security Manager` feature in `tomcat` and was able to make use of the `Catalina.policy` file in managing the permission. 
In spite of which I get this error log for my web-app

[image]

Following are the permissions given in the policy file

```
permission java.io.FilePermission "${catalina.base}${file.separator}logs", "read, write";
permission java.io.FilePermission "${catalina.base}${file.separator}logs${file.separator}*", "read, write"; 
permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.util.logging.config.class", "read";
```

The section of **CATALINA CODE PERMISSIONS** which is present by default in policy file is not modified.I'd created a separate `codeBase` section where I keep my webapps and added the above permissions.

These are the logging handlers that I've enabled in logging.properties file

```
handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = INFO
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = localhost.

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache.level = WARNING

org.apache.jasper.level = WARNING
```

Am I missing something? Please guide me.
Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though this [mkyong link](https://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/tomcat-javasecurityaccesscontrolexception-access-denied-loggingproperties-read/) solves my problem but I think it's kind of hack (I may be wrong too) 
Is it okay to grant all permission to `tomcat-juli.jar`? 
I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4690173/4800126) later which also points to the same above link.

**UPDATE:** 
The error trace was due to excess of logging handlers that were registered in `logging.properties` file deregistering them caused the stack trace to disappear. 
Still, don't know why this

```
permission java.security.AllPermission;
```

Worked though as per the link.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just doing local testing, and there's no need for security, there's also another way, **uncheck "Enable Security"** when you double-click on Tomcat in Eclipse to get the Tomcat configuration.